# embed flash in silverlight

Tags: flash, silverlight, embed

How do you embed a flash video in silverlight, if the source file is provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got the answer,

```
string mediaUrl= http://www.youtube.com/v/h8Ek3v1RBEU&hl=en&fs=1;

HtmlElement mediaContent = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("MediaDiv"); 
HtmlElement mediaObject = HtmlPage.Document.CreateElement("Object");

mediaObject.Id = "mediaObject"; 
mediaContent.AppendChild(mediaObject);

HtmlElement param = HtmlPage.Document.CreateElement("param"); 
param.Id = "MediaID";

param.SetAttribute("name", "movie"); 
param.SetAttribute("value", mediaUrl);

param.SetAttribute("valuetype", "ref"); 
mediaObject.AppendChild(param);

HtmlElement embed = HtmlPage.Document.CreateElement("embed"); 
embed.SetAttribute("src", mediaUrl);

embed.SetAttribute("width", "425px"); 
embed.SetAttribute("height", "344px");

embed.SetAttribute("allowscriptaccess", "always"); 
mediaContent = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("MediaDiv");
        mediaContent.SetAttribute("innerHTML", jsText);
        head.AppendChild(mediaContent); 

mediaContent.SetStyleAttribute("display", "block");
```

This way we can embed a flash file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems not a good idea. But I respect is as it may be your requirement.

Similar discussion avaialble here: http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/257390-Silverlight-can-i-embed-a-flash-object-/

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 3 we've put in place raw audio/video capabilities so yes you could in theory render out .flv into Silverlight. That being said, research your codec licenses here and ensure you comply with Adobe's EULA / Terms & Conditions etc.

**Scott Barnes / Rich Platforms Product Manager / Microsoft.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am developing this application in silverlight 2.0.Is there any way i can do it with silverlight 2.0??

Answer (score 0):

Ramya,

Sorry, not that I know of. Silverlight 3 is the only realistic strategy here, there maybe some ways to bolt it on using your own native wrapper or something along those lines but it's somewhat of a dicey setup to use that approach.

Sorry!