# How to play swf file in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I am tring to play a .swf in silverlight5 page.I am using the ListBox control or Image Control
Or Any Idea To Play swf File in Silvarlight

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Name="bottom_video" Height="80" Source="{Binding VodeoUrl,Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
```

Comment: If Any Control To Play swf file In Silvarlight5 Then suggest me please

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801304/embed-flash-in-silverlight

Comment: yes I Want Proper Solution For Play swf File In Silvarlight 5

Comment: What are the characteristivs of your swf files? What features do they use? Video streaming? Dynamic loading of content? Do they use ActionScript? Do you have access to the .flv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the code below how to use Iframe on Silverlight:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <HyperlinkButton Content="HyperlinkButton" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,20,0,0" Name="hyperlinkButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TargetName="" Click="hyperlinkButton1_Click"  />

    </Grid>



code behind:



private void hyperlinkButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)        { 



HtmlDocument _document = HtmlPage.Document;


            HtmlElement iframe = _document.CreateElement("IFRAME");
            iframe.SetAttribute("src", "http://localhost:52878/TestForm.aspx");


            iframe.SetStyleAttribute("position", "absolute");
            iframe.SetStyleAttribute("top", "100px");
            iframe.SetStyleAttribute("left", "200px");
            HtmlElement body = (HtmlElement)_document.GetElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
            body.AppendChild(iframe);

HtmlDocument _document = HtmlPage.Document;

            HtmlElement iframe = _document.CreateElement("IFRAME");

            iframe.SetAttribute("src", "http://localhost:52878/TestForm.aspx");

            iframe.SetStyleAttribute("position", "absolute");

            iframe.SetStyleAttribute("top", "100px");

            iframe.SetStyleAttribute("left", "200px");

            HtmlElement body = (HtmlElement)_document.GetElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];

            body.AppendChild(iframe);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be able use the the Flash ActiveX control that is automatically installed with the flash player itself on every windows machine but if it works it'd still comes with a lot of limitations as stated [here](http://procbits.com/2010/10/28/silverlight-4-and-comactivex-integration/) another problem will be the ["Airspace" problem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Another way is to convert the SWF to XAML using [this](http://www.mikeswanson.com/SWF2XAML/). But I found quite a lot of swf files that couldn't be converted. Especially if there is a lot of ActionScript or dynamic loading of content involved.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the answer for how to play an swf file in Silverlight 5

```
 <WebBrowser Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding VodeoUrl,Mode=OneWay}" Height="280" Width="280"/>
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness one should add that this comes with the limitations I mentioned in my answer to this question ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/14495506/4227 )

Comment: You Are Not Give Ex For This Issue So I'll Give You Upvot But Accepted By Me

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. Silverlight does not play swf files. If it is just a video file without any interaction, you might be able to convert the video to something that Silverlight can play. Here is some information about the supported formats:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Any Idea To Convert swf file To etc... Format Tharoug the C# Code ?

Comment: Sorry I don't think that is possible. Not unless you can find a 3rd party component with an API that can do the conversion. But I think it is highly unlikely that such a component would exist.