# File download from given URL in silverlight

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to download a file using HtmlPage.Window.Navigate() in IE8 (SL 4).
The new browser window appears briefly and then disappears.

I've tried different settings for trusted sites and the popup-blocker, but nothing seems to help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try a **hyperlink button** to do this. Or try [this solution for opening a new window and passing a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392390/how-to-play-swf-file-in-silverlight)

Happy Coding...